# Why do we require different types of scopes in any application

Tags: spring, javabeans

I am studying Spring framework reference manual, stuck with Spring framework bean scopes. I am not able to picturise the need for scopes.
Can somebody explain the necessity and use case for different types of
scopes.

Answer (score 0):

**Spring Bean Scopes** allows us to have more granular control of the bean instances creation. Sometimes we want to create bean instance as a singleton but in some other cases, we might want it to be created on every request or once in a session.

**The Spring Bean Scopes are as follows**

1. **Singleton** Scopes a single bean definition to a single object instance per Spring IoC container.
2. **Prototype** Scopes a single bean definition to any number of object instances.
3. **Request** Scopes a single bean definition to the lifecycle of a single HTTP request; that is each and every HTTP request will have its own instance of a bean created off the back of a single bean definition. Only valid in the context of a web-aware Spring ApplicationContext.
4. **Session** Scopes a single bean definition to the lifecycle of a HTTP Session. Only valid in the context of a web-aware Spring ApplicationContext.
5. **Global session** Scopes a single bean definition to the lifecycle of a global HTTP Session. Typically only valid when used in a portlet context. Only valid in the context of a web-aware Spring ApplicationContext.

For more details [***read this***](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html) Spring docs.